# SFTP Paramiko (Python) - Import Error DLL Load Failed - Not a valid Win32 Application

Tags: python-2.7, sftp, paramiko

I am a novice Python programmer. I am using a simple paramiko script to download a SFTP file. It started throwing the following error recently: ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. It was working for several months without issue. I am using paramiko 2.1.2, cryptography 1.8.1 and Python 2.7.12 32bit on Windows 7 64bit.

```
>>> t = paramiko.Transport((hostname, port))
>>> t.connect(username=username, password=password)
No handlers could be found for logger "paramiko.transport"
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 1073, in  connect
      self.start_client()
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 493, in start_client
      raise e
   ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall. Rolled back to previous versions, but nothing has resolved this error. I appreciate any help someone can give.

LogFile:

```
    DEB [20170320-10:23:43.359] thr=1   paramiko.transport: starting thread (client mode): 0x29f2250L
    DEB [20170320-10:23:43.359] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.1.2
    DEB [20170320-10:23:43.407] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-WS_FTP-SSH_7.7
    INF [20170320-10:23:43.407] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Connected (version 2.0, client WS_FTP-SSH_7.7)
    DEB [20170320-10:23:43.407] thr=1   paramiko.transport: kex algos:[u'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1', u'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1'] server key:[u'ssh-dss', u'ssh-rsa'] client encrypt:[u'aes256-ctr', u'aes192-ctr', u'aes128-ctr', u'3des-cbc'] server encrypt:[u'aes256-ctr', u'aes192-ctr', u'aes128-ctr', u'3des-cbc'] client mac:[u'hmac-sha1', u'hmac-sha1-96'] server mac:[u'hmac-sha1', u'hmac-sha1-96'] client compress:[u'none'] server compress:[u'none'] client lang:[u''] server lang:[u''] kex follows?False
    DEB [20170320-10:23:43.407] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Kex agreed: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
    DEB [20170320-10:23:43.407] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Cipher agreed: aes128-ctr
    DEB [20170320-10:23:43.407] thr=1   paramiko.transport: MAC agreed: hmac-sha1-96
    DEB [20170320-10:23:43.407] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Compression agreed: none
    ERR [20170320-10:23:43.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Unknown exception: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
    ERR [20170320-10:23:43.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Traceback (most recent call last):
    ERR [20170320-10:23:43.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport:   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 1783, in run
    ERR [20170320-10:23:43.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport:     self.kex_engine.parse_next(ptype, m)
    ERR [20170320-10:23:43.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport:   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\kex_group1.py", line 75, in parse_next
    ERR [20170320-10:23:43.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport:     return self._parse_kexdh_reply(m)
    ERR [20170320-10:23:43.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport:   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\kex_group1.py", line 111, in _parse_kexdh_reply
    ERR [20170320-10:23:43.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport:     self.transport._verify_key(host_key, sig)
    ERR [20170320-10:23:43.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport:   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 1628, in _verify_key
    ERR [20170320-10:23:43.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport:     key = self._key_info[self.host_key_type](Message(host_key))
    ERR [20170320-10:23:43.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport:   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\rsakey.py", line 59, in __init__
    ERR [20170320-10:23:43.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport:     ).public_key(default_backend())
    ERR [20170320-10:23:43.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport:   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\__init__.py", line 74, in default_backend
    ERR [20170320-10:23:43.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport:     _default_backend = MultiBackend(_available_backends())
    ERR [20170320-10:23:43.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport:   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\__init__.py", line 31, in _available_backends
    ERR [20170320-10:23:43.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport:     "cryptography.backends"
    ERR [20170320-10:23:43.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport:   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2308, in resolve
    ERR [20170320-10:23:43.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport:     module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
    ERR [20170320-10:23:43.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport:   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    ERR [20170320-10:23:43.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport:     from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
    ERR [20170320-10:23:43.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport:   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\backend.py", line 16, in <module>
    ERR [20170320-10:23:43.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport:     from cryptography import utils, x509
    ERR [20170320-10:23:43.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport:   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\x509\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    ERR [20170320-10:23:43.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport:     from cryptography.x509.base import (
    ERR [20170320-10:23:43.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport:   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\x509\base.py", line 16, in <module>
    ERR [20170320-10:23:43.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport:     from cryptography.x509.extensions import Extension, ExtensionType
    ERR [20170320-10:23:43.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport:   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\x509\extensions.py", line 19, in <module>
    ERR [20170320-10:23:43.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport:     from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import constant_time, serialization
    ERR [20170320-10:23:43.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport:   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\constant_time.py", line 9, in <module>
    ERR [20170320-10:23:43.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport:     from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._constant_time import lib
    ERR [20170320-10:23:43.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport: ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
    ERR [20170320-10:23:43.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you have a 64-bit Operating system and you are using a package which is 32 bit. This errors come when the base architecture of the machine and the packages installed mismatch.

1. Install  [Microsoft Visual C++ compiler for python](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=44266)
2. pip install wheel
3. pip install paramiko

I tried the below program and it works well.

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('192.168.5.7', username='user', password='mysecretkeya')
uptime = ssh.exec_command("uptime")
print uptime
```

Comment: Thanks Varad. I installed the 64bit Pycrpto but am still receiving the same error.

Comment: Can you try pip install wheel 
pip uninstall pycrypto paramiko 
pip install paramiko this and confirm

Comment: Same error after the uninstall of pycrypto and paramiko then reinstall of paramiko.

Comment: What is the arch of your system. 32 bit or 64 bit.

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: I have made edits to the previous answer. I am using a windows 7 64 bit machine and this same piece of setup works for me. I am using a 64 bit python binary installed as well. Hope its a similar setup for you.

Comment: Thanks Varad for all your help. I ran your suggestions and still didn't work for me. I ended up reinstalling python and it works now.

Comment: Good that it worked. Then you should edit the answer and close the issue

Answer (score 3):

After reinstalling python 2.7 on a 64 bit machine I forced the re-installation of wheel and paramiko

```
pip install --upgrade --force paramiko
```

Comment: I had a mixed install of 64 bit and 32 bit libraries from previous misadventures. So even though it was listed as installed, the mismatch was causing failures. The above answer cleared it up for me.

Answer (score 0):

Final solution for me was to uninstall python 2.7 32bit and paramiko. Then reinstall python 2.1 64 bit and reinstall paramiko. This corrected my error.